# Create a new column based on a column and a named vector

Tags: r

I am looking for a fast and easy way to create a new column in my data.frame by mapping from an existing column and a named vector. For example:

`df <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:8])
vec <- c("A" = "1", "B" = "2", "C" = "3", "D" = "1", "E" = "2", "F" = "3", "G" = "1", "H" = "2")`

From this I want:

`letters numbers
1       A       1
2       B       2
3       C       3
4       D       1
5       E       2
6       F       3
7       G       1
8       H       2`

I was hoping something as simple as this would work:

`df$numbers <- vec[[df$letters]]`

But this gives me

`Error in vec[[df$letters]] : attempt to select more than one element`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `df$numbers <- vec[df$letters]`

Comment: That does the trick, thanks. If you make it an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Happy to help. Feel free to add and accept!

Comment: It's already closed but I suspect that a search on `[r] lookup index` would bring up quite a few duplicates or near duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Pierre Lafortune for the following answer:

```
df$numbers <- vec[df$letters]
```

Comment: I edited your answer a little.  It's always good to give credit where credit is due :)  Plus I edited your code block.

Comment: When answering your own question with the content of someone elses comment, it should be made a community wiki answer imo